# Merging object properties from array

Tags: angular, typescript

I hope the title is accurate but what I have is an array like this:

```
{
  "someValue": 1,
  "moreValue": 1,
  "parentArray": [
    {
      "id": "2222",
      "array": [
        {
          "type": "test",
          "id": "ID-100"
        },
        {
          "type": "test1",
          "id": "ID-200"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "5555",
      "array": [
        {
          "type": "test",
          "id": "ID-100"
        },
        {
          "type": "test1",
          "id": "ID-200"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "444",
      "array": [
        {
          "type": "test",
          "id": "ID-100"
        },
        {
          "type": "test1",
          "id": "ID-200"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to merge all "array" properties together in a new array possibly, to something that looks like this:

```
{
  "someValue": 1,
  "moreValue": 1,
  "array": [
    {
      "type": "test",
      "id": "ID-100"
    },
    {
      "type": "test1",
      "id": "ID-200"
    },
    {
      "type": "test",
      "id": "ID-4400"
    },
    {
      "type": "test1",
      "id": "ID-500"
    },
    {
      "type": "test",
      "id": "ID-600"
    },
    {
      "type": "test1",
      "id": "ID-700"
    }
  ]
}
```

What would be a good way to combine all these properties in Typescript? I'm looking for a Typescript/Angular friendly solution since this will be looped over to create elements in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method on your `parentArray` property to merge inner arrays:

```js
let obj = {
      "someValue": 1,
      "moreValue": 1,
      "parentArray": [
        {
          "id": "2222",
          "array": [
            {
              "type": "test",
              "id": "ID-100"
            },
            {
              "type": "test1",
              "id": "ID-200"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "5555",
          "array": [
            {
              "type": "test",
              "id": "ID-100"
            },
            {
              "type": "test1",
              "id": "ID-200"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "444",
          "array": [
            {
              "type": "test",
              "id": "ID-100"
            },
            {
              "type": "test1",
              "id": "ID-200"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

    let newObj = {
        someValue: obj.someValue,
        moreValue: obj.moreValue,
        array: obj.parentArray.reduce((prev, current) => [...prev, ...current.array],[])
    }
    
    console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this:

```
const obj = {
  someValue: 1,
  moreValue: 1,
  parentArray: [
    {
      id: "2222",
      array: [
        {
          type: "test",
          id: "ID-100"
        },
        {
          type: "test1",
          id: "ID-200"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "5555",
      array: [
        {
          type: "test",
          id: "ID-100"
        },
        {
          type: "test1",
          id: "ID-200"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "444",
      array: [
        {
          type: "test",
          id: "ID-100"
        },
        {
          type: "test1",
          id: "ID-200"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let result = {
  ...obj,
  array: Object.values(obj.parentArray).flatMap(arr => arr.array)
};

delete result.parentArray;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like the use of flatMap, but be careful that you can still support all the browsers you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapper. I usually use lodash for these things: 
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMap

```
const destination = {
    someValue: source.someValue,
    moreValue: source.moreValue,
    array: _.flatMap(source.parentArray, (value) => value.array)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** `this.data.parentArray.map(item => item.array)`:

Try like this:

```
var result = {
  someValue: this.data.someValue,
  moreValue: this.data.moreValue,
  array: this.data.parentArray.map(item => item.array)
};
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwcejb?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: That solution is not entirely correct though, there's multiple arrays where OP wants one array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try next (It will work, with "infinite" nesting):

```
function getChildren(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((items, item) => [...items, ...(item.array ? getChildren(item.array) : [item])], []);
}
```

and call with:

```
getChildren(your_object.parentArray);
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apnk6t)